# Angular getting ChunkLoadError error for lazy loading when path has multiple segment

Tags: angular, routes

I am currently getting the error below when trying to

ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk dashboard-dashboard-module failed.

I have 2 Modules as below:

1. dashboard module
2. product module

Below is my app.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'product', loadChildren: () => import('./product/product.module').then(m => m.ProductModule), 
canActivate: [LoggedInGuard] },
{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => 
m.DashboardModule) }
];
```

My product module has it's own routing which is as below:

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'test', component: TestProductComponent }];
```

If I click on the product navigation where the routerlink is: product/test, it correctly loads the testproduct component.

Note: the url for the above is: localhost:4200/product/test

However if I try to navigate back to the dashboard, it takes the path as:
localhost:4200/**product**/dashboard , instead of localhost:4200/dashboard.

Did I miss out anything from the above and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

How are you navigating back? If there is a back button the use of routerLink might be missing a backslash.

```
<a [routerLink]="['dashboard']">Back</a>  // localhost:4200/product/dashboard 

<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Back</a>  // localhost:4200/dashboard
```

Comment: I have a navigation just like you showed above but still does not work.